# Emberjs input type only accepts string literal from component

Tags: ember.js

These three work:

```
{{input type='text' value=value placeholder=placeholder}}

{{input type='number' value=value placeholder=placeholder}}

{{input type=type name=name checked=checked}} // type: 'checkbox'
```

But the following does not work if `type: 'text'` or `type: 'number'`:

```
{{input type=type value=value placeholder=placeholder}}
```

Does anyone know why that is?

Here's my component, though I don't believe it will help:

```
App.NumberFieldComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    type: 'number',
    value: 3,
    placeholder: 'Number'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just created a jsbin and it's working. Maybe you need to upgrade your ember version?

Component:

```
App.NumberFieldComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    type: 'number',
    value: 3,
    placeholder: 'Number'
});
```

Template:

```
{{input type=type value=value placeholder=placeholder}}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wanuwijobe/2/edit

Comment: Well, I suppose I need to look into it further. Thanks.